# A problematic integral: $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-2\pi i\lambda\cos(t)}\,dt$

Tags: calculus, analysis, integration, special-functions

Is there a special trick to calculate this integral?
$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-2\pi i\lambda\cos(t)}\,dt$$
for $\lambda>0$.

Comment: Looks like a [Bessel function $J_0$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) (at the bottom ; probably what Alpha would tell you...). [Indeed for $\lambda=7$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28exp%28-2*PI*I*7*cos%28t%29%29,t=0..2*PI%29)

Comment: The integral is $2\pi J_0(2\pi\lambda)$, the regular Bessel function of the first kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bessel function of the zeroth order can be [represented by the integral](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9):
$$J_0 (z) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^\pi e^{i z \cos(t)} dt$$
Since the $i\sin(z\cos x)$ part of the exponent is zero over the integral until $2\pi$, only the $\cos(z \cos x))$ remains. This term remains identical through $x\to x+\pi$, so that:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-2\pi i \lambda \cos(t)} dt = 2\pi J_0(2\pi\lambda)$$
As for the original integral, for a proof that this is indeed a solution of Bessel's ODE, see [here](http://www.nbi.dk/~polesen/borel/node15.html).